# how to override the default 200 response in fastapi docs

Tags: python, fastapi, openapi

I have this small fastapi application

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter
from fastapi import Path
from pydantic import BaseModel
from starlette import status

app = FastAPI()


def test():
    print("creating the resource")
    return "Hello world"


router = APIRouter()


class MessageResponse(BaseModel):
    detail: str


router.add_api_route(
    path="/test",
    endpoint=test,
    methods=["POST"],
    responses={
        status.HTTP_201_CREATED: {"model": MessageResponse}
    }
)

app.include_router(router)


def main():
    uvicorn.run("run:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

when I check the docs on `http://127.0.0.1:8001/docs#/default/test_test_post`, in the list of responses in the docs, I see two responses: 200 and 201

I don't have any 200 responses here.
I don't want 200 to be shown for me in the docs.

Here is the fast api auto-generated openapi.json file

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0.2",
    "info": {"title": "FastAPI", "version": "0.1.0"},
    "paths": {"/test": {
        "post": {"summary": "Test", "operationId": "test_test_post", "responses": {
            "200": {
                "description": "Successful Response", "content": {"application/json": {"schema": {}}}
            },
            "201": {
                "description": "Created",
                "content": {"application/json": {"schema": {"$ref": "#/components/schemas/MessageResponse"}}}}}}}
    },
    "components": {"schemas": {
        "MessageResponse": {"title": "MessageResponse", "required": ["detail"], "type": "object",
                            "properties": {"detail": {"title": "Detail", "type": "string"}}}}}}
```

I should not be seeing

```
                "description": "Successful Response", "content": {"application/json": {"schema": {}}}
            },
```

What should I do?

---

UPDATE:

this one also did not work

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter
from pydantic import BaseModel
from starlette import status
from starlette.responses import Response

app = FastAPI()


def test(response: Response):
    print("creating the resource")
    response.status_code = 201
    return "Hello world"


router = APIRouter()


class MessageResponse(BaseModel):
    detail: str


router.add_api_route(
    path="/test",
    endpoint=test,
    methods=["POST"],
    response_model=None,
    responses={
        200: {},
        status.HTTP_201_CREATED: {"model": MessageResponse}
    }
)

app.include_router(router)


def main():
    uvicorn.run("run:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default response can be set with the `status_code` parameter, and the default response model can also be directly controlled by the return type. This [example](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-status-code/) shows you how to do it with the decorator paradigm which is recommended over manually adding API routes.

```
class MessageResponse(BaseModel):
    detail: str

@router.post('/test', status_code=201)
def test() -> MessageResponse:
    print("creating the resource")
    return "Hello world"
```

If you really need to do it with your current structure, you can simply define `status_code` in the `add_api_route` function.

```
router.add_api_route(
    path="/test",
    endpoint=test,
    methods=["POST"],
    status_code=201,
    responses={
        status.HTTP_201_CREATED: {"model": MessageResponse}
    }
)
```

Comment: this is different from the structure of my application

Comment: I am using `router.add_api_route`

Comment: but your solution gave me a hint on how to solve my problem with the structure of mine

Comment: I know this is a different structure from your application. This is the structure recommended by FastAPI whereas your structure is non-standard which would make it difficult to find documentation. The `status_code=201` would still work if you put it inside `add_api_route`, but again, that is not what the documentation recommends.

Comment: fastapi is flexible and friendly and there is no recommended structure. you can restructure it the way you want. and it should give you the same features in any structure you use it

Comment: A chair is flexible and friendly and there is no correct way to sit on it, but if you sit on it sideways you can't lean back on the backrest, and your legs will hang over the armrest. If you are comfortable sitting in that position, sure, I'm not going to judge you, but for the sake of your health, I recommend you sit in the way most other people are sitting.

Comment: in no production-level big application, sitting straight (the simplest way of creating a fastapi application) will suffice.

Comment: In a case where a patient has severe spinal deformation, sitting straight alone will not fix it. Instead, you would combine sitting straight (simple, clear structure) with surgery or visiting a chiropractor (more advanced features). Continuing to sit sideways (using a suboptimal structure) will not help.

Comment: I dont believe such abstract examples are helpful in a technical discussion

Comment: Well if we are to discuss in technical terms, the structure I use is less code to write overall, saving valuable developer time. This structure is also standard, meaning 99% of FastAPI developers would be familiar with this structure increasing the productivity of collaborators should a team become necessary when the scale of this application becomes large enough. Almost all community support including YT tutorials, SO questions, GH issues, and even the Official FastAPI Documentation use this structure.

Comment: I agree that community support including YT tutorials, SO questions, GH issues, and even the Official FastAPI Documentation use this structure. I am not well-informed because I dont have access to a study but I dont believe big application follow the simple fastapi structure provided in the documentation.
the same story about flask.

Comment: `do it with the decorator paradigm which is recommended over manually adding API routes` - Citation, please? Seems highly dependent on the use case, rather than simply "recommended" wholesale.

Answer (score -1):

this solution works but it is not ideal

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter
from pydantic import BaseModel
from starlette import status
from starlette.responses import Response

app = FastAPI()


def test(response: Response):
    print("creating the resource")
    response.status_code = 201
    return "Hello world"


router = APIRouter()


class MessageResponse(BaseModel):
    detail: str


router.add_api_route(
    path="/test",
    endpoint=test,
    methods=["POST"],
    response_model=None,
    status_code=201,
    responses={
        status.HTTP_201_CREATED: {"model": MessageResponse}
    }
)

app.include_router(router)


def main():
    uvicorn.run("run:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have to repeat 201 twice. it is redundant.

I thin this is a bug in fastapi.

Ideally I should not need to do this

Comment: This is intended behavior in FastAPI and definitely not a bug. The default response model exists to reduce code in most circumstances. See my answer for an example of how.

Comment: @Squarish but when you list responses, the default should be removed. I should not need to define 201 twice

Comment: You don't have to list the default in `responses`. You can move the response model directly to the type hint of your endpoint function. Doing this here makes it unnecessary to have `responses=...` at all.

Comment: I have multiple responses and multiple models for each

Comment: in that case, you would define the default with `status_code` and endpoint return type hint, and then define other responses with `responses`. Still results in less code overall and makes it more intuitive what is the expected result versus error/edge case results.

Comment: I dont agree. I have and endpoint that returns 204, 401, 403, 404.
I am defining their models in `respnses={204: {.....}, 401: {.....}, 403: {.....}, 404: {.....}` and then I have to again define `status_code=204` to get rid of 200 in the openapi.json file

Comment: In this case, you would remove `204: {'model': PyModel}` from `responses` completely and move it to `test() -> PyModel:` adding `status_code=204` to specify that the hinted response is a 204.

Comment: then response models for 401, 403, 404 are not in the same place as the response model for 204. they will be in two different part of the code. I want them all to be in the same place

Comment: I understand the desire to put all models in the same place, but here, they shouldn't be. If you'll notice, 204 is a 2xx Success response whereas the others are all 4xx Client Error responses. 204 is the expected successful response and should be distinct from the others.

Answer (score -2):

You can override the default response by setting it to an empty dictionary.

```
router.add_api_route(
    path="/test",
    endpoint=test,
    methods=["POST"],
    responses={
        200: {}, # Override the default 200 response
        status.HTTP_201_CREATED: {"model": MessageResponse}
    }
)
```

It should not be present in your documentation anymore but if you want the 200 status code no longer present, you will need to do so explicitly in your code.

```
from fastapi import status
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

def test():
    print("creating the resource")
    return JSONResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, content={"detail": "Hello world"})
```

Comment: see my updated question. your solution does not work